# QWebEngineView Closes application without error in a clean Windows installation but works fine in development Windows (Where QT creator is)

Tags: windows, qt, qtwebengine

I have a QT application that uses QWebEngineView with the following code:

```
void MainWindow::showWebPage()
{
    QWebEngineView *view = new QWebEngineView(parent);
        view->load(QUrl("https://www.google.com/"));
        view->show();
        ui->centralLayout->addWidget(view);
        this->setWindowTitle("About my App");
        this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
}
```

If I run the application in the development environment (Qt Creator + Qt 5.12 + Visual Studio 2019 + Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041) the code runs fine. But if I zip it with the required DLLs and open it on another Windows 10 machine the application closes without error. I tried to run in on console but no message at all.

I redistribute the following files:

```
myApp.exe
db.sqlite
d3dcompiler_47.dll
libEGL.dll
libGLESv2.dll
opengl32sw.dll
platforms
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Network.dll
Qt5OpenGL.dll
Qt5Positioning.dll
Qt5PrintSupport.dll
Qt5Qml.dll
Qt5Quick.dll
Qt5QuickWidgets.dll
Qt5Sql.dll
Qt5WebChannel.dll
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll
Qt5WebEngineWidgets.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
QtWebEngineProcess.exe
qwebengine_convert_dict.exe
sqldrivers
styles
```

Maybe I missing some files but I cannot find on the internet information about redistributing Qt5WebEngine

Any clue is appreciated

Comment: did you create an exe file with windeployqt?

Comment: your problem is look like [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/66460/problem-with-running-the-application-with-qwebengineview/2)

Comment: @Parisa.H.R . You are right. I used windeployqt and it created everything I needed. Thanks!!! Now my App runs as expected.

Comment: you're welcome.